# Symfony 4 base controller class for all other API controllers

Tags: php, api, symfony, controller, symfony4

In my Symfony 4 application I need to have a multiple Controllers, each to mount/group various API endpoints in different prefix's.

Each controller will need to initialize first and set in a class property the API client and set the credentials. To avoid code repetition across all of them, I'd like to create a BaseController so the others can extend and directly access or have available the client property with all he needs.

The base controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Vendor\ApiClient;

class BaseApiController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var ApiClient
     */
    protected $apiClient;

    public function __construct( array $apiClientCredentials, ApiClient $apiClient )
    {
        $this->apiClient = $apiClient;
        $this->apiClient->credentials($apiClientCredentials['id'], $apiClientCredentials['main_password']);
    }

}
```

One of the many similar controllers that I want to have the API property ready to be called/used:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

/**
 * Account endpoints
 * @Route("/account")
 */
class AccountApiController extends BaseApiController
{

    /**
     * Get the balance.
     * @Route("/balance", name="balance")
     */
    public function balance()
    {
        return new JsonResponse($this->apiClient->getBalance());
    }
}
```

This is what I have but still doesn't work as expected, wondering how is the best practice to put this setup together?

Edit: This is the error message I get.

```
Cannot autowire service "App\Controller\AccountApiController": argument "$apiClientCredentials" of method "App\Controller\BaseApiController::__construct()" must have a type-hint or be given a value explicitly.
```

Edit: Adding my `services.yaml`

```
# config/services.yaml
parameters:
    app.creds:
        id: '%env(ACCOUNT_ID)%'
        main_password: '%env(ACCOUNT_MAIN_PASSWORD)%'
# ...
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
    # ...
    App\Controller\BaseApiController:
        arguments:
            $apiClientCredentials: '%app.creds%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i'm going to use it in multiple controllers seems for now it's fair just binding the argument.

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      
        autoconfigure: true 
        public: false      
        bind:
            $walletCreds: '%app.wallet_creds%'
```

Also the base class has to be an abstract:

```
abstract class BaseApiController extends Controller
{
//...
```

Answer (score 5):

The scope of your APiClient needs to be protected

```
/**
 * @var ApiClient
 */
protected $apiClient;
```

Comment: You are right, I had the wrong scope for `$apiClient` now I've changed it on my code to `protected`. However, that's not the cause or the solution to my question. See the error message I have added above if that helps to give more context.